# Instant Messenger for Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, default-programs, instant-messaging

Does anyone know if there is an instant messenger that can (easily) be installed and work on both Windows (7) and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/download/) works well on both

> Pidgin is an easy to use and free chat client used by millions.
>   Connect to AIM, MSN, Yahoo, and more chat networks all at once.
>
> Supported chat networks:
>
> - AIM
> - Google Talk
> - IRC
> - MySpaceIM
> - Sametime
> - Zephyr
> - Yahoo!
>
> Find More [Here](http://www.pidgin.im/)

[image]

Screenshot from [Run Skype as a daemon and manage it from Empathy or Pidgin in Ubuntu 11.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/run-skype-as-a-daemon-and-manage-it-from-empathy-in-ubuntu-11-04)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/pt-br/get-skype/) on my windows 7, Ubuntu and my Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Pidgin a try. Pidgin works both on GNU/Linux and MS Windows. Furthermore, Pidgin was like default IM client before all those fancy empathy stuff.

Edit: To give more detail, Pidgin supports MSN, Google Talk, XMPP, Yahoo, IRC and many more networks that you can check on http://pidgin.im.